# RSA Encryption in Jmeter for Response Value

Tags: encryption, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am currently working in a application where RSA Encryption is being used for Encrypting sensitive data. Is there a way to use RSA Encryption in Jmeter so that this value appears encrypted in the previous response? Below is an example,

The actual value,
"emailAddressInfo" : ("PerfTestA@gmail.com | PerftestB@gmail.com").

I want the above value to appear encrypted like below in Jmeter.

"emailAddressInfo": "(as15114677sfh0hfu4scr460hdhsb24sjj324j689hsakw42cjjftks4wefe4sd)"

The mix of characters represent the encrypted value.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like an RSA-encrypted message to me so I would recommend double-checking the algorithm.

Whatever, in order to RSA-encrypt a string you need to use [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Example code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

                //replace with your own RSA public key
def publicKey = 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsvX9P58JFxEs5C+L+H7W\n' +
        'duFSWL5EPzber7C2m94klrSV6q0bAcrYQnGwFOlveThsY200hRbadKaKjHD7qIKH\n' +
        'DEe0IY2PSRht33Jye52AwhkRw+M3xuQH/7R8LydnsNFk2KHpr5X2SBv42e37LjkE\n' +
        'slKSaMRgJW+v0KZ30piY8QsdFRKKaVg5/Ajt1YToM1YVsdHXJ3vmXFMtypLdxwUD\n' +
        'dIaLEX6pFUkU75KSuEQ/E2luT61Q3ta9kOWm9+0zvi7OMcbdekJT7mzcVnh93R1c\n' +
        '13ZhQCLbh9A7si8jKFtaMWevjayrvqQABEcTN9N4Hoxcyg6l4neZtRDk75OMYcqm\n' +
        'DQIDAQAB'


def x509PublicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.decodeBase64())
def keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance('RSA')
def key = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509PublicKey)

def string2Encrypt = '("PerfTestA@gmail.com | PerftestB@gmail.com").'

def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA')
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

def secretMessage = string2Encrypt.getBytes('UTF-8')
def encryptedMessage = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessage)

def encodedMessage = encryptedMessage.encodeBase64().toString()

vars.put('encodedMessage', encodedMessage)
```

Once done you will be able to refer the encrypted value as `${encodedMessage}` where required.